# String as primary key hibernate and postgres

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I is it possible to use a String as a primary key in an Entity. I tried it but its get converted to a biginteger in my postgres db?

Comment: Of course it's possible. Why would it be converted to a bigint? Have you defined the column as a varchar in Postgres?

Comment: I had hibernate generate the tables. From @Entity